# jQuery collapsible div, collapsing 2nd div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm a designer trying to find a fix to my jQuery collapsible div problem. (I'm new to jQuery, but I have a good handle on html and CSS). I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for in the forums, so I'm giving this a shot. Hopefully someone can help me out.

I have a panel with a header tab and 2 `divs`. I want the have the open/close trigger (with graphic) in the panel tab and have only the second div close when targeted. I wan the first `div` to always show, and the 2nd `div` is the options which I would like to open/close when selecting a button in the panel tab.

I'm using Ramin Hossaini collapsible `div` code as a starting point:

Here's the **CSS**:

```
h1 {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

p {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.module {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width: 400px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.module .header  {
    background-color:#efefef;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.module .header h1 {
    margin:0;
    display:inline;
    font-size:16px;
}

.module .content{
    clear:both;
    padding:10px;
}

.module .placeholder {
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-right:2px;
}

.module .expand {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    background-image:url(../images/toggle-sprite.png);
    background-position: 0px -16px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
}   

.module .collapse {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    background-image:url(../images/toggle-sprite.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Here's my **html:**

```
<div class="panel module">

<div class="panelTab header">
    <h1>Header #1</h1>
</div>

<div class="content 1">
          <p>I want this content to always show.</p>
     </div>

<div class="content 2"> <!-- the 'content' class is only for styling -->
    <p>I want this panel to collapse and expand.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

And the **jquery** which I don't fully understand:

```
jQuery.collapsible = function(selector, identifier) {

//toggle the div after the header and set a unique-cookie
$(selector).click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function() {
        if ( $(this).is(":hidden") ) {
            $.cookie($(this).prev().attr("id"), 'hide');
                 $(this).prev().children(".placeholder").removeClass("collapse").addClass("expand");
        }
        else {
            $.cookie($(this).prev().attr("id"), 'show');
            $(this).prev().children(".placeholder").removeClass("expand").addClass("collapse");
        }
    });
    return false;
}).next();


//show that the header is clickable
$(selector).hover(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
});

/*
 * On document.ready: should the module be shown or hidden?
 */
var idval = 0;  //increment used for generating unique ID's
$.each( $(selector) , function() {

    $($(this)).attr("id", "module_" + identifier + idval);  //give each a unique ID

    if ( !$($(this)).hasClass("collapsed") ) {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).append("<span class='placeholder collapse'></span>");
    }
    else if ( $($(this)).hasClass("collapsed") ) {
        //by default, this one should be collapsed
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).append("<span class='placeholder expand'></span>");
    }

    //what has the developer specified? collapsed or expanded?
    if ( $($(this)).hasClass("collapsed") ) {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).next().hide();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).children("span").removeClass("collapse").addClass("expand");
    }
    else {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).children("span").removeClass("expand").addClass("collapse");
    }


    if ( $.cookie($(this).attr("id")) == 'hide' ) {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).next().hide();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).children("span").removeClass("collapse").addClass("expand");
    }
    else if ( $.cookie($(this).attr("id")) == 'show' ) {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).next().show();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("id") ).children(".placeholder").removeClass("expand").addClass("collapse");
    }


    idval++;
});

};
```

Comment: The given jquery only affects the first div following the header.  Using that jquery plugin as it stands, you won't get what you want, you need to write your own or find another that will target the div you want to toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following jquery:

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){
    if($('#toggle').text()==='Open'){
        $('#collapsible').slideUp();
        $('#toggle').text('Close');
    }else{
        $('#collapsible').slideDown();
        $('#toggle').text('Open');
    }
});
```

you can see it woking in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhTpW/

Comment: @Idmo: How could this be modified to use an image to open and close? I don't want any copy, I just want to use images (1 for open, 1 for closed)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use that jQuery code at all, but rather a simpler one:

```
jQuery( function(){
    jQuery(".panel .panelTab").css("cursor","pointer").click( function(){
        if( jQuery(".panel .2").toggle().is(":visible")){
            jQuery(this).removeClass("collapse").addClass("expand");
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("expand").addClass("collapse");
        }
    });
});
```